# Domain Maintenance Controls/Forms, is there a Pattern?

Tags: winforms, design-patterns, data-binding

I'm working on an application that has a large domain - i.e. Customers, SalesOrder, Suppliers, Products, Stocks etc. - and have discovered that the WinForms data binding is a little too restrictive for what I need.

Is there a useful *design pattern* for setting up the populating of forms and updating of the underlying data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly have you considered using WPF, its data binding is a lot better?

There are some 3rd party data entry controls that will layout all the fields and labels etc base on data binding. E.g. [XtraVerticalGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Vertical_Grid/) with a single column.  Lots are on the market, ask a more detail quesion if you need pointers about them.

Comment: I have considered WPF but the learning curve (unless I'm just being ignorant) appears to be too steep.  However, I fully intend to work with WPF in the near future.  Thanks for your help.